# Retrieving objects in Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++

I just want to preface this by saying I am little new to all this, so please bear with me. So for our assignment we have to implement our own Binary Search Tree. We are to use this BST to create an Address Book of objects of type ExtPersonType(which has varying members etc).

For the most part everything looks good and works, but for the life of me I can't figure out these three functions. I have to essentially display all info of that object by searching the tree for last name, month, and status.

They are all very similar functions so I won't belabor with all of them. If someone can point me in the right direction for one of them I believe I can figure it out. Thanks for your help in advance!

*I have stripped alot of the code to hit the high points. Let me know if you want me to post more*

```
BinarySearchTree
template<class T>
class BinarySearchTree
{
private:
     Node<T>* root; 
public:
    BinarySearchTree() { root = NULL; }
    void displayInfo(T value);
    bool search(T value);

template <class T>
bool BinarySearchTree<T>::search(T value)
 {
    Node<T>* tree = root;

while (tree)
{
    if (tree->value)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (tree->value > value)
    {
        tree = tree->left;
    }
    else
    {
        tree = tree->right;
    }
}
return false;
}

template <class T>
void BinarySearchTree<T>::displayInfo(T value)
{
Node<T>* tree = root;

while (tree)
{
    if (tree->value)
    {
        cout << tree->value;//I have overloaded << here to display objects (works btw)
    }
    else if (tree->value > value)
    {
        tree = tree->left;
    }
    else
    {
        tree = tree->right;
    }
    }
}
```

AddressBook.cpp.

```
AddressBook<ExtPersonType> addressBook;
ExtPersonType person;

int main()
{
   //reads input from file
        person.setInfo(firstName, lastName, 
                             month, day, year, 
                             street, city, state, zipCode, 
                             phoneNumber, status);

        addressBook.insert(person);
      }
}

void optionThree()  //The crux of my problem
{
 string lastName;
 cout << "Enter the last name of the person: ";
 cin >> lastName;
 addressBook.printInfoOf(lastName);
}
```

AddressBook.h

```
template <class elemType>
class AddressBook : public BinarySearchTree<elemType>
{
public:
 AddressBook();
 void printInfoOf(string);
 void printNameInTheMonth(int);
 void printNamesWithStatus(string);
};


// Print - Info Of
template <class elemType>
void AddressBook<elemType>::printInfoOf(string lastName)
{
  if(person.getLastName() == (last))
    BinarySearchTree::displayInfo(person);
  else
    cout << "Not found" << endl;
}
```

As you can see I have no idea what I'm doing. Thank you once again!

> error C2451: conditional expression of type 'ExtPersonType' is illegal 
>   No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, >or the operator cannot be called
>   documents\visual studio 2010\projects\programming4\binarysearchtree.h(234): >while compiling class template member function 'void >BinarySearchTree::displayInfo(T)'
>            with
>            [
>                T=ExtPersonType
>            ]

Comment: Is `ExtPersonType` convertible to a `bool`?

Comment: ExtPersonType is entirely another class that further inherits from other classes such as AddressType (class to set address), DateType(class to set dob), to essentially make a "Person" that has first name, last name, phoneNum, address, etc...

Comment: If `ExtPersonType` is not convertible to a `bool` then why is it being used for an if statement: `if (tree->value)` in displayInfo?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. As mentioned I have no idea how to even start on the function. I was just simply posting something that I tried (which is obviously way way wrong)...sorry that couldn't help you

Comment: The error message states that that is the reason you are getting the error, most of your code looks fine otherwise. You will want to check whether `ExtPersonType` has overloaded the `operator >` as well.

Comment: So basically the tree has objects of ExtPersonType. Each object has a multitude of members that is holds...first name, dob, address, etc. How can I search the tree of objects to look for  the object based on some criteria? That is my problem basically. Putting it all together. If anyone could provide a code example or use mine. Thanks once again to everyone who responded!

Answer (score 1):

In your `BinarySearchTree::displayInfo` method you have the following line:

```
else if (tree->value > value)
```

This line is doing a greater-than comparison between two objects of type ExtPersonType, but there is no default `operator>` for custom classes.

If you haven't implemented something like

```
bool operator>(const ExtPersonType & other) const { ... }
```

in your `ExtPersonType` class, then that's your problem.

Don't forget, if you implement `operator>`, you should also implement `operator<`, `operator>=`, and `operator<=`.

Generally, one should consider `operator>` and `operator<=` as a related pair, and `operator<` and `operator>=` as another related pair, and implement one of each pair as the negation of the other, e.g.:

```
bool operator>(const ExtPersonType & other) const {
    return !(*this <= other);
}

bool operator<=(const ExtPersonType & other) const {
    // Do your actual comparison here
}
```

Implementing your comparisons in this fashion reduces your chances of errors down the road, if you need to change how two `ExtPersonType` objects relate to each other.

Comment: Hi Nathan, thanks for your response. I have actually done this already.
    `bool operator > (const ExtPersonType right);
bool operator < (const ExtPersonType right);
 bool ExtPersonType::operator < (ExtPersonType bob){
  return (lastName < bob.getLastName());
 }
 bool ExtPersonType::operator > (ExtPersonType bob){
  return (lastName > bob.getLastName());
 } `

Comment: I made some assumptions about your original code, let's check some of them. Is this line `binarysearchtree.h:234`? `if (tree->value)`. If so, is `value` an object, or a pointer to an object?

`if (tree->value)` will work fine if it's a pointer, but if it's an object then you'll need to either define a comparison, or override `operator bool()`

In fact, should that line maybe read `if (tree->value == value)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone who responded. Nathan, you were right in part of the problem was that I wasn't comparing the value (tree->value == value). The other part was an issue with how I was passing the parameters, but I got the entire thing working now. Thanks!